# Visa Category for tourist and work in the US

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, work

I have a B1B2 US visa and have gotten a 3months internship in the US. the Internship is full time and unpaid and I will be going back to my country after that. Do I need to change my visa or will it serve the purpose.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html#overview (Hint: the PDF linked from that page explicitly answers your question)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to change your visa.

The [US State department explains](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html#overview) that on a B type visa, the valid business uses are such:

> - consult with business associates
> - attend a scientific, educational, professional, or business
>     convention or conference
> - settle an estate
> - negotiate a contract

Now obviously an internship is none of these. However, the list is not exhaustive, an they [link to a PDF flier](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf) that explains a variety of business travel reasons and the visa (if any) that would be required. It states:

[image: US Visa Internship]

```
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Purpouse of your travel |                                          About your temporary visit                                          |                        Type of visa                         |                                                                      Key Steps                                                                       |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Internship              | Practical training through an internship with a U.S. based employer, whether paid or unpaid by that company. | Temporary worker trainee (H-3) or Exchange Visitor (J) visa | H - U.S. employer files petition with USCIS. J – Applicant approval by J sponsor. After above approval, visa application at U.S.Embassy or Consulate |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So it seems the company offering your internship would need to apply for a H type visa.

Comment: Hmm, tables don't seem to be working

Comment: I reformatted the table using http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html I also added a screenshot of the table (I usually do this when I have a hard time quoting formatted stuff). Pick the one you like best or feel free to rollback if neither suit you. ;)

Comment: Gah, I spent all the time making a table like that too, hit submit and was beaten to it by seconds by you, @JoErNanO :D

Comment: We can't use markdown tables in TSE then - https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables

Comment: @CMaster apparently not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: @Fatima is this answer answers your question to your satisfaction, please accept (click the tick icon next to it).